# What are these Windows filename transformations?

Tags: windows, windows-7, autohotkey, path, command-line-arguments

i use Windows 7 x64.
If i right-click on folder called `C:\Longer than (3)` and click "Send to" and send it to an .ahk file that simply shows the arguments it received, it shows `C:\LONGER~3`.
Same happens with almost all files, for example `C:\Новый текстовый документ.txt` becomes → `C:\700C~1.TXT`.

**How do i convert those paths to normal ones?** And what are those path convertions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called
[8.3 filename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) :

> An 8.3 filename (also called a short filename or SFN) is a filename convention used by old versions of DOS and versions of Microsoft Windows prior to Windows 95 and Windows NT 3.5. It is also used in modern Microsoft operating systems as an alternate filename to the long filename for compatibility with legacy programs.
> ...
> The stripped name is then truncated to the first 6 letters of its basename, followed by a tilde, followed by a single digit, followed by a period ., followed by the first 3 characters of the extension.

The digit is just a counter. For `C:\LONGER~3`, you might have or had
3 files that started with `C:\LONGER`.

This format allows converting file-names to a format that does not
contain a special character, and especially blanks. It's very
useful for deleting files that have invisible special characters
in their name, or passing them as parameters that do not contain
blanks (which might otherwise be truncated to the first blank).

There is no functional need to convert these names to the
long format, as they  work as well as the long ones.

For multiple ways to convert 8.3 names to the long format, see the
post
[How can I convert a Windows short name path into long names within a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34473934/how-can-i-convert-a-windows-short-name-path-into-long-names-within-a-batch-scrip).

Comment: "There is no functional need to convert these names to the long format, as they work as well as the long ones."
But i created this post solely because of that need. i want to display the user a friendly name of that folder / file.

Well, thank you for answering, now i know where to dig!

Comment: Since i work with Autohotkey, i ended up using this AHK technology: A_LoopFileLongPath

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't get the original filename. But you can disable this option via command:

```
fsutil.exe 8dot3name set D: 1
```

this will disable it for disk `D`. To disable it system-wide use command like:

```
fsutil.exe behavior set disable8dot3 1
```

P.S. Not sure if this command is available in Windows 7